# Destroy VS Remove operations in Gemfire

Tags: java, gemfire

What is the difference between [destroy(java.lang.Object)](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/apidocs/tgf-82/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Region.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) and [remove(java.lang.Object)](http://com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.Region#remove(java.lang.Object)) operations in Gemfire?

Both operations does what are described on Javadocs, but the reason for having two methods is not clear as their javadocs states basically the same:

> Destroys the entry with the specified key. Destroy removes not only
> the value but also the key and entry from this region. Destroy will be
> distributed to other caches if the scope is not Scope.LOCAL. Does not
> update any CacheStatistics.

vs

> Removes the entry with the specified key. The operation removes not
> only the value but also the key and entry from this region. Remove
> will be distributed to other caches if the scope is not Scope.LOCAL.
> Does not update any CacheStatistics.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only difference is in how they handle missing entries. `destroy` will throw an `EntryNotFound` exception, whereas `remove` will return null. So destroy might be useful to tell the difference between a null stored in the region or an entry that is actually missing.